# Find same values in two huge datasets

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, list, search, bigdata

i have a list with roughly 2 000 rows [UnixTimestamp, Value01, Value02](it comes as a JSON) and i have another list which has a few million rows [UnixTimestamp, Value01, Value02] (it comes as a .csv) I want to figure out if each element in the smaller list has an element in the second list with the same values.
Both the lists are sorted by the timestamp

The simplest way is obviously something like that:

```
for x in small_List:
    if x in big_list:
        return True
    return False
```

But does that make sense or is there a more efficient way?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any relation between `UnixTimestamp`,`Value01`,`Value02` ?

Comment: You could try giving a cut down version of the two datasets to aid solution writing. In general two lists of lists could become two sets of tuples then the set intersection computed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are already sorted by timestamp, so use that to your advantage:

```
big_list_index = 0
for x in small_list:
    y = big_list[big_list_index]
    while big_list_index < len(big_list) and y.timestamp < x.timestamp:
        big_list_index += 1    
        y = big_list[big_list_index]
    while big_list_index < len(big_list) and y.timestamp == x.timestamp:
        if y.timestamp == x.timestamp and y.value01 == x.value01 and y.value02 == x.value02:
            return True
        else:
            big_list_index += 1 
            y = big_list[big_list_index]
```

If timestamps are unique, complexity is O(len(big_list) + len(small_List))

Answer (score 1):

If they are just lists, you can try something like this.

`set(small_list) & set(big_list)`

Converting to `set` will remove the duplicate values and you can use `&` operator to compare and result back the same values of the two sets.

Comment: Great idea thanks.
The data doesn't come in a list yet but i planned to format it for that reason.

Comment: The cast to a set doesn't work since i guess the list actually contains lists.

Comment: What is the time complexity of this?